# "Lights off" puzzle

Tags: java, performance, swing

Lights Off is a puzzle game consisting of an \$n\times n\$ grid of lights. At the beginning of the game, some of the lights are switched on. When a light is activated, it and its four neighbors in the cardinal directions are toggled. The objective is to turn off all the lights.

Input:

```
000
110
010
```

Output should be

```
000
000
000
```

by selecting cells \$(0,0)\$, \$(1,0)\$, \$(1,1)\$, \$(2,1)\$, and \$(2,2)\$

I'd like to know if my code can be made any more efficient.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class lightOff extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  public static final int W = 400;
  public static final int H = 200;
  JButton[][] lights = new JButton[3][3];
  int COLS = 3, ROWS = 3;
  public lightOff()
  {
      super("Light Off"); 
      setSize(W,H);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[][] input = {{"0","0","0"},{"1","1","0"},{"0","1","0"}};
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
         for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
          {

            lights[i][j] = new JButton(); // Initializing all JButton
            lights[i][j].addActionListener(this); // Registering listener 

            lights[i][j].setText(input[i][j]); // setting text of each 
                                               // button as per input String
            add(lights[i][j]);  // adding JButton to the JFrame

          }
       }

     }
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       lightOff obj1 = new lightOff();
       obj1.setVisible(true);
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       JButton action = (JButton)e.getSource();
       if(action==lights[0][0])
        {
       if("0".equals(lights[0][0].getText()))
          lights[0][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[0][0].setText("0");
         // edgeToggle(0,0,action);
       forward(0,0);
       down(0,0); 

      }

      else if(action==lights[0][1])
      {
        if(lights[0][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[0][2].setText("1");
        else 
          lights[0][2].setText("0");

        backward(0,1);
        forward(0,1);
        down(0,1);
   }

   else if(action==lights[0][2])
   {
       if(lights[0][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[0][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[0][2].setText("0");
         // edgeToggle(0,2,action);
       backward(0,2);
       down(0,2);
   }

   else if(action==lights[1][0])
   {
     if(lights[1][0].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][0].setText("0");

     up(1,0);
     down(1,0);
     forward(1,0);
   }

   else if(action==lights[1][1])
   {
     if(lights[1][1].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][1].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][1].setText("0");

     up(1,1);
     down(1,1);
     backward(1,1);
     forward(1,1);
   }


   else if(action==lights[1][2])
   {
     if(lights[1][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][2].setText("0");

     up(1,2);
     down(1,2);
     backward(1,2);
   }



   else if(action==lights[2][0])
   {
       if(lights[2][0].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][0].setText("0");
        //  edgeToggle(2,0,action);
       up(2,0);
       forward(2,0);

   }

   else if(action==lights[2][1])
   {
     if(lights[2][1].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][1].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][1].setText("0");

     up(2,1);
     backward(2,1);
     forward(2,1);
   }


   else if(action==lights[2][2])
   {
       if(lights[2][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][2].setText("0");
   //       edgeToggle(2,2,action);
       up(2,2);
       backward(2,2);
   }
   }



   public void forward(int a, int b) // calling to check status 
                                     // of next Jbutton in same row
   {
      if("0".equals(lights[a][b+1].getText()))
       lights[a][b+1].setText("1");
      else
       lights[a][b+1].setText("0");
   }

  public void backward(int a, int b) // calling to check status of previous 
                                     // JButton in same row.
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a][b-1].getText()))
       lights[a][b-1].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a][b-1].setText("0");
   }

   public void up(int a, int b) // calling to check status of Jbutton 
                                // above the current one.
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a-1][b].getText()))
       lights[a-1][b].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a-1][b].setText("0");
    }

   public void down(int a, int b) // calling to check status of Jbutton
                                  // below the currrent Jbutton.
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a+1][b].getText()))
       lights[a+1][b].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a+1][b].setText("0");
   }


   }
```

Answer (score 10):

I wonder how this generalizes to e.g., a 30x30 game. Would it be 100 times longer?

```
public static final int W = 400;
```

Why public?

```
JButton[][] lights = new JButton[3][3];
```

This should be private. Actually, everything should be always private, unless there's good reason against.

```
 int COLS = 3, ROWS = 3;
```

These are constants and should be be `private static`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
   JButton action = (JButton)e.getSource();
   if(action==lights[0][0])
```

Don't call the button "action". I'd suggest

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (source == button[i][j]) {
           handle(i, j);
        }
     }
  }
```

Note the spacing and braces; that's the normal Java style. A single loop instead of the n**2 cases. Now simply call toggle for the selected coordinates and all 4 neighbors (they may be off, but let's handle it by the callee).

```
private void handle(int i, int j) {
    toggle(i, j);
    toggle(i+1, j);
    toggle(i-1, j);
    toggle(i, j+1);
    toggle(i, j-1);
}
```

And now start by testing if we're in range:

```
private void toggle(int i, int j) {
    if (0 <= i && i < ROWS && 0 <= j && j < COLS) {
        JButton toggling = lights[i][j];
        String oldText = toggling.getText();
        String newText = "1".equals(oldText) ? "0" : "1";
        toggling.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Don't call the button "action". I'd suggest_"... what? What do you suggest?!

Comment: This is unrelated: I'd suggest... the piece of code below the sentence. Concerning the name, maybe just "button" or "source" or "target" (source of the event, target of what happens). I don't like "action" as 1. there is `java.swing.Action`, 2. the "action" is some toggling, the button is its target/object.

Comment: Actually, I was referencing that you never actually state the new variable name you'd suggest, you just directly use it in the code.

Comment: Hey maaartinus, thanks for correcting me syntactically, do you think if this program can be made more optimal ?

Comment: @ProgOptimal Optimal? Do you mean "fast"? Do you expect user making thousands clicks per second? Or do you want to write a solver for this problem?

Comment: @maaartinus, can we make program more efficient by reducing line of code  as compared to the logic or semantics that I have used in actionPerformed method ?

Comment: or if we can follow any particular algorithm to resolve it !!!!

Comment: @ProgOptimal Just keep it short and clean. I didn't really correct you syntactically. I shortened your code by a factor of (nearly) 9. There's no algorithm needed as you don't compute anything complicated, just flip 5 things per click. So I'm lost what you're talking about. +++ The only improvement I can imagine is separation of computation and UI, so that it's more usable and allows e.g. generalization to bigger boards or writing a solver.

Comment: @maaartinus, do u have any logic that the cells (ie buttons) get selected automatically in the series of (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1), and (2,2) by using doClick() method ? So that we do not need to click them!!!

Comment: @ProgOptimal Just call `handle(1, 0); handle(1, 1);` etc.

Answer (score 8):

Note: Each successive tip assumes you've already implemented all of the ones before it, so I recommend reading this in order and implementing it in order.

#### Generic advice

- ***NEVER USE `==` TO COMPARE STRINGS. IT MAY WORK NOW, BUT IT WILL FAIL LATER. REPLACE EVERY INSTANCE OF `==` THAT'S USED TO COMPARE
  STRINGS WITH `equals`.***
- Indents in Java are, by convention, *exactly* four spaces or a single
  tab. You alternately use three, four, two, and (in *several*
  instances) zero or *negative one* spaces to indent. This is *very*
  bad. If you don't want to stick to convention, at least be
  consistent. I'm assuming an indentation of four spaces.
- Related to the last point, *always* indent *exactly* one level after
  an open curly brace. Deindent one level after a closing curly brace. In
  exactly zero other cases should you indent (at least in this code;
  there are a few others, but if you use a real IDE it'll take care of
  those for you).
- Classes in Java are always UpperCamelCase -- so `LightOff`, not
  `lightOff`. (Though I have a point to make about your class' name in
  **Specific Advice** -- see below)
- You should have exactly one blank line before and after every method
  declaration.
- Open curly braces (`{`) go on the same line as the `if`, `for`, etc. or
  method/class declaration they're paired with. As an example,

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  ```
- Comments about methods are wrapped in `/**  */` and go *before* the
  method. They are not sets of single-line comments between the body of
  the method declaration and its bracket. They also describe what the
  method does, not what it might sorta do kinda if you rewrote some
  code. Anyway, as an example, this:

  ```
   public void forward(int a, int b) // calling to check status 
                                     // of next Jbutton in same row
   {
  ```

  becomes this:

  ```
   /**
    * Toggle the cell in (a, b+1).
    */
   public void forward(int a, int b) {
  ```

  Ideally, you'd have `@param` annotations to describe what `a` and `b`
  are. I suggest you read up on Javadoc syntax. It's *very* useful when
  you start writing real code.
- Never use one-line `if`s with the result on the next line. For
  example, this:

  ```
   if("0".equals(lights[a+1][b].getText()))
       lights[a+1][b].setText("1");
  ```

  should be this:

  ```
   if("0".equals(lights[a+1][b].getText())) lights[a+1][b].setText("1");
  ```

  Otherwise, if you try to add a statement and you forget your
  curly braces, you'll get bugs galore.
- Put spaces around your operators! It makes it much easier to read.
  For example, this:

  ```
  (action==lights[0][0])
  ```

  becomes this:

  ```
  (action == lights[0][0])
  ```
- Same thing applies to commas/comma-separated values, which means that
  this:

  ```
  String[][] input = {{"0","0","0"},{"1","1","0"},{"0","1","0"}};
  ```

  becomes this:

  ```
  String[][] input = {{"0","0","0"}, {"1","1","0"}, {"0","1","0"}};
  ```
- Keywords (e.g. `if`, `for`) always have a space before and after
  them:

  ```
  if(action == lights[0][0])
  ```

  to

  ```
  if (action == lights[0][0])
  ```
- You have a lot of newlines before `}`s and just after `{`s. Get rid
  of those.
- There should be a space after every `;` that isn't at the end of a
  line.
- Variable and method names should be meaningful. `obj1` is not
  meaningful. `forward` is not meaningful.
- `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is generally better to use than
  `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, because instead of just exiting the program entirely, it
  disposes of the one window only, *then* exits if none are left. If you get into this habit and make a project with several windows, you won't spend two and a half hours figuring out why your whole project exits when you close one window.
- Comments explain *why*, not *what*. Your code is right there. We see
  the *what*. Explain *why* you did it that way. (Incidentally, this
  means that most of your comments, other than the method explanations,
  are useless.)
- `else if` should be on the same line as the `}` that closes the
  previous `if`/`else if`, or at least on the line directly afterwards.

#### Specific advice

- The puzzle is called the "Lights off puzzle", so why is your class
  called `LightOff`? It should be `LightsOff`.
- You defined `COLS` and `ROWS`, then never used them -- instead, you
  used the magic constant `3`. At this point, I'm too tired to really
  care, so I just got rid of the named constants.
- You also defined `kb`, then never used it. Instead, you hardcoded the
  input value. Got rid of that, too, which meant that the
  `java.util.Scanner` import line was unused, so I got rid of that.
- Your `actionPerformed` could definitely be refactored to be something
  *other* than a massive block of `if`/`else if`, but I'm not doing that for you. Call it an exercise for the reader, or look at the other answer.

With all those suggestions, here's what your code looks like:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LightOff extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static final int W = 400;
    public static final int H = 200;
    JButton[][] lights = new JButton[3][3];

    public LightOff() {
        super("Light Off"); 
        setSize(W,H);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String[][] input = {{"0","0","0"},{"1","1","0"},{"0","1","0"}};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                lights[i][j] = new JButton();
                lights[i][j].addActionListener(this);

                lights[i][j].setText(input[i][j]);
                add(lights[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LightOff obj1 = new LightOff();
        obj1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton action = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if (action == lights[0][0]) {
            if ("0".equals(lights[0][0].getText())) lights[0][0].setText("1");
            else lights[0][0].setText("0");

            forward(0,0);
            down(0,0);
        } else if (action == lights[0][1]) {
            if (lights[0][2].getText().equals("0")) lights[0][2].setText("1");
            else lights[0][2].setText("0");

            backward(0,1);
            forward(0,1);
            down(0,1);
        } else if (action == lights[0][2]) {
            if (lights[0][2].getText().equals("0")) lights[0][2].setText("1");
            else lights[0][2].setText("0");

            backward(0,2);
            down(0,2);
        } else if (action == lights[1][0]) {
            if (lights[1][0].getText().equals("0")) lights[1][0].setText("1");
            else lights[1][0].setText("0");

            up(1,0);
            down(1,0);
            forward(1,0);
        } else if (action == lights[1][1]) {
            if (lights[1][1].getText().equals("0")) lights[1][1].setText("1");
            else lights[1][1].setText("0");

            up(1,1);
            down(1,1);
            backward(1,1);
            forward(1,1);
        } else if (action == lights[1][2]) {
            if (lights[1][2].getText().equals("0"))
                lights[1][2].setText("1");
            else lights[1][2].setText("0");

            up(1,2);
            down(1,2);
            backward(1,2);
        } else if (action == lights[2][0]) {
            if (lights[2][0].getText().equals("0")) lights[2][0].setText("1");
            else lights[2][0].setText("0");

            up(2,0);
            forward(2,0);
        } else if (action == lights[2][1]) {
            if (lights[2][1].getText().equals("0")) lights[2][1].setText("1");
            else lights[2][1].setText("0");

            up(2,1);
            backward(2,1);
            forward(2,1);
        } else if (action == lights[2][2]) {
            if (lights[2][2].getText().equals("0")) lights[2][2].setText("1");
            else lights[2][2].setText("0");

            up(2,2);
            backward(2,2);
        }
    }

    public void forward(int a, int b) {
        if ("0".equals(lights[a][b+1].getText())) lights[a][b+1].setText("1");
        else lights[a][b+1].setText("0");
    }

    public void backward(int a, int b) {
        if ("0".equals(lights[a][b-1].getText())) lights[a][b-1].setText("1");
        else lights[a][b-1].setText("0");
    }

    public void up(int a, int b) {
        if ("0".equals(lights[a-1][b].getText())) lights[a-1][b].setText("1");
        else lights[a-1][b].setText("0");
    }

    public void down(int a, int b) {
        if ("0".equals(lights[a+1][b].getText())) lights[a+1][b].setText("1");
        else lights[a+1][b].setText("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to SHOUT. Making it bold is enough to emphasize, or you could underline it too

Comment: "Mustaches" is not a common way of calling *curly braces*. And the convention is to use `PascalCase` for class names, `camelCase` for variable and method names, `SHOUT_CASE` for immutable constants, and `snake_case` is not a convention, but acceptable in unit test case names

Comment: @janos With regards to shouting, in this case I felt it necessary because it's going to save a lot of trouble later. With regards to mustaches, I could have sworn I clarified somewhere in there that they're not really called that, but it's what I like to call them. Feel free to edit and change the names if I didn't.

Comment: I would like to thank you guys for picking up my faults and correcting me at very specific places like naming variables, methods, indetation.
I would be more happy if you can rate my program, in terms of optimality as well as specify any optimal solution for this program.

Comment: @ProgOptimal I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer then. Like I said in the question, if you clean up your code, you could ask another about making it more efficient, though the other answer mostly covered that.